Google account history shows many apps starting with com.android, what are those apps?
Phone is T-mobile Revvl. Google account history and activity gives me this.



Are they apps from Google Play? I couldn't find anything in my apps.

Does the name not give a hint to what each one maybe for. Please spe ify the one that's puzzling you.

These are absolutely normal applications, the packages of which usually belong to the system.
These also include "com.google.*".
You cannot delete most of these programs, since they often are required for the stability and operation of the system.

All of these com.android names are internal components of the Android operating system. There's nothing frightening about them.
They are used by apps, and com.android.launcher3 is the default program launcher, which starts apps and provides the home screen.
If you can explain a bit more about where you're seeing these reports, we may be able to explain more.

I believe this is from Google My Activity

This is the list of Android apps used by you.
